# Google Meet: How can i catch the url?

Tags: meeting-request

I need to open a new google meet room, and send it. I can't use standard "share" button in app. I need to catch the final url.
I can't catch that with curl (it's not a normal redirect).
My idea is that i need to open a request/link in background or in the same page, wait some second and catch the link, after i can release the page and user can enter.

Do you know something that can help me?

Edit:
Yes, i had miss to tell that i need to generate a room from a click and catch the url from code. Generally, i should to make this with Google Calendar API, but in this case i can't.

Comment: I believe you need to remove `openmeetings` tag from this question, it is unrelated to "Apache OpenMeetings" :)))

Comment: sorry! done, ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use google Calendar API. I make a webApp for my organization, that from a form (with user information to send togheter meet link) make a google calendar event with google meet room (from google loggedin user account), catch the link and send it by a smsGateway.

```
        function FormForMeet (Args) {
    
    // get calendar name, if it already exists
    var meetsCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName ('CalendarName');
      Logger.log (meetsCalendar.length)
    
      if (meetsCalendar.length> = 1) {
// if some calendar be found, it catch the first, obviously here you can use some differet method. I had choose this because I don't expect to find more than 1
        var calendar = meetsCalendar [0] .getId ();
      }
      else
      {
    // If miss, create new one.
        var calendar = CalendarApp.createCalendar ('CalendarName', {summary: 'descrip Calendar',
// set a color of calendar label :D
        color: CalendarApp.Color.PURPLE});
        calendar = calendar.getId ();
      }
      
    // Call function to create meet
     var LinkMeet = CreateConference_ (calendar);
     
// here you can use what you want for send Args + LinkMeet);
    
    // if you want return link
     return LinkMeet;
    }

    // Function to create Conference. You can obviously use the code up without make a new function.
    function CreateConference_ (calendarId) {
    
    // Custom of event, here I created the conferences according to my needs (now, with 1 h / conference)
      var now = new Date ();
      var start = new Date (now.getTime ()). toISOString ();
      var end = new Date (now.getTime () + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)). toISOString ();
// generate random string to request
      var rdmreqId = genStrg ();
    
      var event = {
      "end": {
         "dateTime": end
         
      },
      "start": {
        "dateTime": start
         
      },
      "summary": "conferenceName",
      "conferenceData": {
        "createRequest": {
          "conferenceSolutionKey": {
            "type": "hangoutsMeet"
          },
          "requestId": rdmreqId
        }
      }
    
      };
    // insert event in calendar
     event = Calendar.Events.insert (event, calendarId, {
        "conferenceDataVersion": 1});
    // if use the function you can return the link to send
      return event.hangoutLink
    }
    // random strind
    function genStrg () {
      var data = "something";
      var text = "";
      var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789! @ # $% & <> * -";
    
      for (var j = 2; j <= data.length; j ++) {
        text = ""; // Reset text to empty string
    
        for (var i = 0; i <possible.length; i ++) {
          text + = possible.charAt (Math.floor (Math.random () * possible.length));
        }
    
        return text;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

all google meet links look something like this:
`https://meet.google.com/abc-defg-hij`
You should be able to just copy and paste this link from your browser page. If someone enters this link, they will be taken to the meet lobby and they can enter at any time.

If you can't access this link for some reason, like if you're on mobile, you have to put your meet code (the `abc-defg-hij`) at the end of the aforementioned url.

edit: You actually can find the link if you're on mobile by going into your meeting lobby and scrolling down until you get to "joining information". Under that there should be the meeting link and the numbers to join by phone.

Comment: Yes, i had miss to tell that i need to generate a room from a click and catch the url from code. Generally, i should to make this with Google Calendar API, but in this case i can't.